# PushSharp “get json on NotificationSent ” issue

Tags: c#, cordova, push-notification, console-application, pushsharp

I used PushSharp DDL, 
I am trying to save the status of the notification send in my database.
on NotficationSent Event, I will update my database with status=true where NotificationID=XXXX
NotficationSent event includes my JSON which I pushed  in parameter (notification)

I try to get my JSON in SentNotification Event  to know My NotificationID  I wrote this code but  it did not work.

```
static void NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
    {
var push = (PushSharp.Android.GcmNotification)notification;
    json =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic(push.JsonData);
    var NotificationID=json.NotificationID
    }
```

the  code is not completed run it stopped at this line with no error and the function is exit, I can not get NotificationID in my variable

```
json =Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic(push.JsonData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INotification` is just an interface and the `JsonData` property is not part of that interface.  The parameter instance passed in may not in fact be a `GcmNotification` type, so you should check to ensure it is and then case to it:

```
static void NotificationSent(object sender, INotification notification)
{
  var gcmNotification = notification as GcmNotification;
  if (gcmNotification != null) {
    var json = JObject.Parse (gcmNotification.JsonData);
    var notificationId = json["NotificationID"].ToString ();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this as my code, but when I run and debug this code, the code not completed  it stopped at below  line and exit  from the function
  var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(gcmNotification.JsonData);

after above line the rest of the code not run to get NotificationID
this line did not run because the function is exit 
 var notificationId = json.NotificationID;

Comment: I updated my sample to not use deserialization... This should just grab the `NotificationID` value from the json object.  Keep in mind `JsonData` has whatever *you* put in it, so you are responsible for adding the `NotificationID` key/value pair if you want it available in that event.